# if Regex describes regular language - Why Catastrophic Backtracking?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I wonder why [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with stackoverflows can occur, considering regex describe a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory) and these can recognized by a [finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). As far as I know, a finite automaton has constant memory consumption.

Comment: Because the adjective "regular" in the "regular expression" word combination has changed from *qualitative* to *relative*. Most of the regex flavors are no longer "regular".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite state automatons and regular expressions being able to describe the same set of languages doesn't mean that they work the same. Yes, they are equivalent in their scope, and you can find a finite state automaton for any regular expression (and reverse) that match the same language, but this translation is not easy.

Regular expressions can be trivially converted into a [nondeterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), but executing those can take a long time (they do backtracking as well). You could equally convert them into [deterministic finite automatons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), but those are no more as small in storage as the NFAs.

It's just a trade-off. In what format are you describing your regular language, and what algorithm is used to match it against your input? Regular expressions that are evaluated with backtracking work very well. That you can build regular expressions that lead to catastrophic backtracking is only a minor nuisance - you can also build a different expression for the same language that doesn't. You can even automatically detect catastrophic backtracking, and rewrite the expression, but the trade-off is that this task is too costly to be done every time a regex is compiled so it's left to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Most libraries and tools implementing things that they call regular expressions are not actually implementing regular expressions.  For example, back references are not possible in true regular expressions.  Further, most tools do not actually implement regular expressions using a DFA translation (even when the regexp is actually a regular expression) but use much less efficient techniques.

For discussion of the latter point, see e.g. https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html